# How do I draw an image with an alpha channel to a TSpeedButton?

Tags: delphi, vcl, delphi-xe4, alphablending

I've got a `TSpeedButton`, and a `TImageList` that holds various glyphs.  One of them has an alpha channel, and it looks very nice when drawn to certain parts of the UI... but when that glyph is drawn on a `TSpeedButton`, it doesn't take the alpha channel into effect.

Looking at the relevant code in `TButtonGlyph.DrawButtonGlyph`, it's getting passed `true` for the `Transparent` parameter, but `Transparent` isn't taken into account at all in the `if FThemesEnabled` code path; it only gets referenced in the **else** section.  Since this program has themes enabled, does that mean it's impossible to draw an alpha-blended image to a `TSpeedButton`?

Is there any way to work around this?

**EDIT:** Looking at this a bit more closely, it appears that it takes transparency into account... sort of.  Pixels that are fully transparent don't get drawn at all, which is correct behavior.  But the antialiasing (partial transparency) around the edges gets drawn as fully opaque.

Comment: In case David Heffernan reads this: **do not** ask for code samples or I will flag you.  This is not a question about my code; this is a question about the way the VCL draws images in a highly specific context.  Thank you.

Comment: `DrawThemeIcon`: *Draws an image from an image list with the icon effect defined by the visual style.* - So this is the icon effect, whatever that means..

Comment: Actually, AFAICS, it draws partial transparency alright, but draws it against a white background. Maybe that color is visual style dependent.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: As your (excellent) answer demonstrates, all of the relevant information is already there, and knowing that wouldn't have changed anything.  For the record, the property was set up with `ImageList.GetBitmap(index, SpeedButton.Glyph);` but would knowing that have really made any difference at all?

Comment: @Mason I don't know. Probably not. The answer here needed studying of a fair bit of code, but it's vcl code that you could not post. I think your first comment was a little mean. I often ask for code for good reason. See the edit history on today's tree view AV question for instance. I think I know what I'm doing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From what I can see, `TSpeedButton` takes your bitmap and adds it to an image list. That's `FGlyphList` in the private section of `TButtonGlyph`. That image list has `ColorDepth` of `cdDeviceDependent`. You'd need that image list to have `ColorDepth` of `cd32Bit` if you wanted alpha transparency to be respected. So that right there explains the artifacts.

I'm not sure how you go about working around this. I think that I'd personally subclass `TButtonGlyph` and connect it directly to an image list of your selection. Then replace `TButtonGlyph.DrawButtonGlyph` with code that draws from your image list. I'm sure you'll be able to work out the coding.

But there'll be no simple workaround. Without major modifications to the VCL, that image list is going to use `cdDeviceDependent` and there's no simple way for you to change that. There's no obvious quick fix that I can see.

Actually, what I would do would be to use `TButton`, but that's just me.

---

Regarding the `Transparent` property of the speed button the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Buttons.TSpeedButton.Transparent) says:

> Specifies whether the background of the button is transparent.
>
> Use Transparent to specify whether the background of the button is transparent.
>
> This property works only if the Flat property of the TSpeedButton is set to True.
>
> When Windows themes are enabled, the Transparent property cannot make the button background transparent.

That is, the property influences the button background, for flat buttons, when unthemed, and has no relevance to glyph drawing.

Comment: Just using TButton isn't an option; I need a button with a `Down` state that can be used like a checkbox.  I may have to look at third-party components, if this is what's going on under the hood. Thanks.

Comment: You could just build your own button using `TSpeedButton` as a template. You can cut out lots of the cruft that you don't need.

Answer (score 1):

In the interest of full disclosure: I ran into a similar problem and used this Q&A to base my **initial** solution on.  Since I needed a quick fix for my app and compiler (I use C++ Builder 2009) I decided to 'hack' the VCL's private members and set `Glyphlist`'s `ColorDepth` to `cd32Bit`, until I had time to work on something more permanent.  This hack worked, with a few more changes, but was **far** from ideal, for all the obvious reasons, but also functionality wise, there were issues to consider.

However, while doing so I experimented further and finally arrived at below, working solution, without any dirty tricks needed.  Not being that familiar with the internal workings of VCL and the rather 'it's not possible as is' feedback from people who are far more in depth in VCL I'm a bit unsure on what I'm missing right now !?  Because below solution works for me.  Confirmed on XP, XP-High-contrast, W7 and W10.  The Glyphs don't look good on W2K but then that is true for Main Menu and Popup icons as well, so that is that.

I code in C++ but use the same underlying VCL, so I will post my C++ solution here, as answer to a Delphi question.  I hope that is OK, in the interest of offering a path to a solution rather than keeping it to myself.  A Delphi guru can convert and post as answer as well then, unless I'm missing something and my solution isn't what was needed all along.

Since I started with the 'hack' approach first I subclassed `TSpeedButton` and put the code in a MyTSpeedButton function, but that is not needed to make this work.  However, it is the code that I'm posting:

**header**

```
class MyVCLTSpeedButton : public TSpeedButton
    {
    public:

    __fastcall MyVCLTSpeedButton(Classes::TComponent* AOwner) ;

    void __fastcall AddGlyphWithAlphaChannel(Imglist::TCustomImageList* ImageList, int UpIndex, int DisabledIndex = -1, int ClickedIndex = -1, int DownIndex = -1) ;

    };
```

**cpp**

```
void __fastcall MyVCLTSpeedButton::AddGlyphWithAlphaChannel(Imglist::TCustomImageList* ImageList, int UpIndex, int DisabledIndex, int ClickedIndex, int DownIndex)
{
Glyph->Assign(NULL) ; // Clear the current bitmap 

NumGlyphs = (DisabledIndex > -1)?((ClickedIndex > -1)?((DownIndex > -1)?(4):(3)):(2)):(1) ;

Graphics::TBitmap *BitMap = new Graphics::TBitmap ;

//BitMap->AlphaFormat = afDefined ; // Don't Change AlphaFormat, it will negatively affect rendering !
BitMap->PixelFormat = pf32bit ;   // Doesn't seem to be that important
BitMap->Height = ImageList->Height ;
BitMap->Width  = (ImageList->Width * NumGlyphs) ;

BitMap->Canvas->Brush->Color = Parent->Brush->Color ;
BitMap->Canvas->Brush->Style = bsSolid ;
BitMap->Canvas->FillRect(BitMap->Canvas->ClipRect) ;

TIcon *Icon = new TIcon() ;

for (int x = 0 ; x < NumGlyphs ; x++)
    {
    ImageList->GetIcon((x == 0)?(UpIndex):((x == 1)?(DisabledIndex):((x == 2)?(ClickedIndex):(DownIndex))), Icon) ;
    BitMap->Canvas->Draw((ImageList->Width * x), 0, Icon) ;
    }

Glyph->Assign(BitMap) ;

delete Icon ;
delete BitMap ;
}
```